# Azure Mobile Services (DB)

Tags: database, macos, azure, blob, azure-mobile-services

I came from Parse to Azure and faced the problem with Azure Mobile Services. When I'm trying to setup data tables in the browser it is possible to add attributes with 4 types only, such as String, Number, Date and Boolean. It is not enough for me.

Can anyone help me how can I obtain other types (BLOB, Pointer, etc.)?

I'm new to Azure and working with OSX.

[image: attribute types]

Comment: You can try use SQL table instead, check this blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2013/05/24/using-an-existing-azure-sql-table-with-windows-azure-mobile-services/

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to manage blobs is through azure blob storage you can find how to do this through https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage/

The best way to manage the tables is through Microsoft Management Studio and connect it to Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Thank you for response, I think it is quite problematically to use MS Management Studio, and I hoped that there was an another approach.

Comment: Nevertheless, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming from Parse, why not continue to use Parse?

See: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-welcomes-parse-developers/

Azure Mobile Apps / Services both deal with SQL Database Tables - if you are on an ASP.NET backend, you can support anything that Entity Framework supports.  However, SQL databases tend to be more involved than most Parse developers are used to.

If you are just switching, but want to use the same development experience, just continue using Parse Server.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Actually, I thought about Parse Server, but I feel, that in future I will need to use some features which are not supported by Parse Server. Furthermore, My project is not so big, so I don't need to continue to use Parse, and it will be better to try Azure or AWS.